# Track git branch starting from specific commit

Tags: git, version-control, branch, commit

Suppose I have 2 branches. I want one branch to track another branch starting from a specific commit, so that when there are new commits in the branch that is being tracked, old commits are not merged into the tracking branch.

Is it possible to do it in git? My problem is that I don't want to have some old commits in a new branch but I need to get automatically new commits from another branch, excluding some of the old commits.

Answer (score 0):

Branch names are just records storing a commit ID.

What you are asking for here is to store a specific commit ID under a name, and then later, compare some other branch *name*'s commit ID to the saved commit ID.  This is precisely what branches and tags *do*: they're names for commit IDs.

The only real difference between a branch name and a tag name is that a branch name is *designed to move*, and in fact *moves automatically* when one is "on" that branch and makes commits:

```
       o--o       <-- branch1
      /
...--o--o--o      <-- HEAD -> branch2
           ^
           |
            \-------- tag: tagX
```

Here `HEAD` points to `branch2`, meaning you're on branch `branch2`: you've done `git checkout branch2` recently.

Now if you make a *new* commit (let's mark this one with `*` instead of `o`), the graph becomes:

```
       o--o       <-- branch1
      /
...--o--o--o--*   <-- HEAD -> branch2
           ^
           |
            \-------- tag: tagX
```

Note how the tag has not moved.

If we use a branch name, rather than a tag name, it *still* doesn't move, though.  Let's rewind to before the new commit, and draw this as:

```
       o--o       <-- branch1
      /
...--o--o--o      <-- branchX, HEAD -> branch2
```

Now we make the new commit.  Because we're on branch `branch2`, and *not* on `branchX`, only `branch2` changes.  So I'll draw this a bit differently just to fit the branch arrows:

```
       o--o       <-- branch1
      /
...--o--o--o      <-- branchX
            \
             *    <-- HEAD -> branch2
```

Note that this is precisely the same *graph* as with the tag—I've merely drawn the tag's arrow a bit differently, to imply that the tag's arrow is closer to the commit itself (because tags are never supposed to change, while branches *are* supposed to change).

Thus, all you need to do here is create a name (branch name or tag name), pointing to the specific commit you want to remember:

```
git branch branchX <commit-ID>
```

or:

```
git tag tagX <commit-ID>
```

Which should you use, tag, or branch?  That depends on whether you want to move it, and whether or how you want other people to share it.  Tags are never supposed to move, and are pretty global: other people who clone your repository get, as *their* tags, *your* tags.  Branches *are* supposed to move, and are not so global: other people who clone your repository get your branches, but as `origin/*` names, not as *their* branch names.

(If you don't want either of these—if you want the name not to move, but also not to be global, for instance—you can invent your own name-space.  Branches and tags are built in, and Git knows what to do with them.  If you invent your own reference name-space, Git won't know how to work with it, so you will have to do more work.)